# When does btrfs allocate space?

Tags: btrfs

I would like to know when btrfs allocates space?

the background of this question is that using the two commands

1. `btrfs filesystem show` and
2. `btrfs filesystem df /`

which provides this output on my system:

```
$> btrfs filesystem show
 Label: none  uuid: xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
     Total devices 1 FS bytes used 25.77GiB
     devid    1 size 40.00GiB used 26.53GiB path /dev/sda1

$> btrfs filesystem df /
 Data, single: total=25.00GiB, used=24.48GiB
 System, single: total=32.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
 Metadata, single: total=1.50GiB, used=1.29GiB
 GlobalReserve, single: total=82.64MiB, used=0.00B
```

it seems that while the second command `btrfs filesystem df /` indicates that most everything of the `Data, single` is used, the first command `btrfs filesystem show` seems to tell me that there is still some roughly 13GiB space left.

Therefore the question:
When does `btrfs` allocate the space? Do I have to care, or does this happen automaticly (for all entries like `Metadata, single`, `System,single`)?

Additionally should the values of both commands correspond / "add up?"?

Comment: I think you should take these detailed technical questions to the BTRFS mailing list. You'd have a better shot at getting answers there; assuming you've already done your homework. Their Wiki also has links to papers which describe the internals of the filesystem. I believe one of them discusses allocation.

Comment: just a sidenote, `btrfs fi usage <path>` shows allocation and usage combined.